# Automatically updating Buffer FeatureClass when creating new features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer, update

I have a roads FeatureClass, and I've built a buffer for it. I will still make edits to the road FeatureClass.

Let's say I add a new segment of road, how can I automatically buffer the new segment without creating a new buffer FeatureClass?

I use ArcGIS Desktop 10.1

Apparently when using Geomedia if your information changes in your data source, so does the analysis in the workspace. I want to know if ArcMap can do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buffering tool creates a new output FeatureClass. What you could do is create a model that you run to create a buffer as a new temporary dataset in the **in_memory** workspace and then [append](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000050000000) that to your existing buffer FeatureClass. The assumption behind this approach is that you are creating buffers from NEW features and not features you have edited (e.g. extended an existing polyline).